# Send data from angular to Laravel Route

Tags: angular, laravel

I've an angular application and a laravel Backend. I want to send some data from angular service file to laravel route and process that data there.

In angular service file I've created sociallogin function and in laravel site I've created route 'sociallogin' in api.php

**api.service.ts**

```
    const postData = {
      data: Data
      };
    return this.getHttpClientPost(this.baseUrl + '/sociallogin', postData);
  }
```

**api.php**

`Route::post('socialLogin',       'AuthController@socialLogin');`

I'm getting these errors

> RouteCollection.php line 255 
>   RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))  RouteCollection.php
>   line 242  RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request),
>   array('POST'))  RouteCollection.php line 176 
>   RouteCollection->match(object(Request))  Router.php line 612

Please correct my steps to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

### 1

For starters, you have a typo, in your api.php, you have defined the route as `socialLogin`

and in your angular service, you are calling: `sociallogin`

They should both be the same.

### 2

Now I am not sure what http client service you are using but make sure that you are using POST method from your angular service, not GET one.

Correct above two points and you should be good to go